# How to do this kind of confirmation dialog?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, confirmation

I am creating a website, and I want to do like this kind of confirmation dialog.. how can I do this? if the user will going to exit my website while he is processing something there..

[image]

I found this kind of confirmation dialog in facebook.

Comment: Just a suggestion, consider using a nice dialog like this: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/.

Comment: @gustavodidomenico IMHO, the styling is not the issue here. The requirement is to catch attempts to leave the page and allow the user to reconsider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to handle `beforeunload` event. Note that it works differently across browsers.

See sample implementation here: https://gist.github.com/4125388

Answer (score 0):

```
 <form name=myform>
     <input type=button value="Try it now" onClick="if(confirm('Format the hard disk?')) alert('You are very brave!');else alert('A wise decision!')">
 </form>
```

Comment: You can leave the page by clicking back, or by typing new address, or by clicking anything else on the page other than that button... These need to be handled too.